# Converting Object to and from JSON

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot

Maybe someone help me and tell which structure of object should be for successful converting to and from JSON like this?

```
{"converted":{"BYN":  {"amount":  "753.48",  "currency":  "BYN"},  "USD":  {"amount":  "350.00",  "currency":  "USD"}}}
```

I have tried create object but it did not work:

```
public enum Currency {
    USD,
    BYN;
}

public class CurrencyInfo {
    private Double amount;
    private Currency currency;
} 

public class Converted {
    private Map<Currency, CurrencyInfo> convertedAmount;
}
```

Where were I wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you either rename `convertedAmount` to `converted` (or use `@JsonProperty("converted")`)?

Comment: Don't forget public setters and getters in your classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following for `Converted` class:

```
class Converted {
    private Map<Currency, CurrencyInfo> converted;

    public Map<Currency, CurrencyInfo> getConverted() {
        return converted;
    }

    public void setConverted(Map<Currency, CurrencyInfo> converted) {
        this.converted = converted;
    }
}
```